# Extraneous column and row headings appeared in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

Two rows and two columns appeared in a worksheet when Excel updated. They are above the Column headings and to the left of the row headings, both labeled 1 and 2. If I click on 2, I get the normal worksheet.

If I click on 1, I get extreme parts of the worksheet below or to the right of the area I'm working on. The worksheet is designed to expand by columns by adding data to the right, so the sum functions contain references way to the right.

How do I get rid of these additional headers? What are they? They clog up the display.

Comment: Pleas edit your question and give it a more meaningful title.

Comment: this question would be better with a screenshot rather than just a description.  Use windows "snip".  You can upload an image from the clipboard directly here, don't even need to save it.  Just ctrl v on the upload screen

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the outline and group function for tabular data.

If you know that you don't want it, you can clear it with Data ribbon > Ungroup dropdown > Clear outline. But you really want to make sure you don't destroy someone else's useful setup.

The outline and group in conjunction with the Subtotal formula can be used to keep large tables manageable, instead of having to scroll pages over pages.

Learn more about this functionality in this [Microsoft Help article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). It's been written for Excel 2007 but it still applies to your version.

Comment: As a note to the OP, it's also possible to hide the column headings (A, B, C...) to make some extra room if all you want is to "unclog" the display. This may or may not fit your use case, but I thought I'd mention. Just go into View on the Ribbon and uncheck Headings in the Show group, or type `Alt` `W` `V` `H`

Comment: @AndreTerra That won't remove the grouping panels on the left and above the headers.

Comment: No, it won't but it frees up some space which is his goal